# Algorithm for Uneven Product allocation in Multiple Warehouses with PHP

Tags: php

I have a script which returns the ID's of the warehouses (4,1,2,10,9) in order how close they are to the customer.

`$warehouse_rank = array('0'=>4,'1'=>1, '2'=>2, '3'=>10, '4'=>9);`

When I lookup a product from the database, I return a breakdown of which warehouses have it in stock and the quantity. Like so:

```
$product_breakdown = array(
    'storage'=>array(
        '10001'=>array(
            'total_stock'=>89,
            'breakdown'=>array(
                '4'=>0,
                '1'=>89,
                '2'=>0,
                '10'=>0,
                '9'=>0
            )
        )
    )
);
```

`10001 is the product ID in this case.`

I made this loop to determine which warehouse has the desired quantity, so then I can order it:

```
foreach ($warehouse_rank as $key => $warehouse_id){
    if($product_breakdown['storage'][$product_id['output']]['breakdown'][$warehouse_id] >= $posted->order->quantity) {
    }
}
```

However the problem is this will only detect when the requested quantity is available as whole in the warehouse.

I cannot wrap my head around how to go about when the requested quantity is spread out in multiple warehouses.

---

**For example:**

They request 20 pieces.

And the distribution is as follows `'4'=>5pc, '1'=>5pc, '2'=>1pc, '10'=>8pc, '9'=>10pc`.

So ideally the warehouses will be assigned something like this: `WID:4=5pc, WID:1=5pc, WID:9=10pc.`

There are two factors, how close the warehouse is; but also to accomplish the allocation with the least warehouses possible.

---

Any ideas, suggestions how to approach this?

The number of warehouses is dynamic, there could be more or less warehouses. And I'd like to take out as much quantity as possible from the closest warehouse. Thats why I have `$warehouse_rank`.

*PS. I'm not looking for help on how to make the actual order. Just the quantity allocation per warehouse.*

Comment: So if as in your second example the customer should receive four separate packages, in total 20 pieces?

Comment: It's for wholesale customers. In some cases they will receive the order in parts, in others it will be combined with other items. But thats not necessary at the moment, I can't figure how to allocate certain quantities per multiple warehouses. So then they can prepare the quantity thats been allocated to them. To ideally get something like WID:4=5, WID:1=5, WID:9=10 @Andreas

Comment: This sort of "best fit" algorithm is going to be non-trivial, has nothing to do with PHP, and is not well-suited for SO. I suggest asking on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Wait I see now your added example. `WID:4=5, WID:1=5, WID:9=10.` why not take from the other two warehouses that is closer? That contradicts your first statement

Comment: @Andreas Because that would mean 4 packages instead of 3. Closeness is a factor but also to do it with the least steps (warehouses) possible.

Answer (score 2):

Alter your database query so it adds a generated column. Have it calculate the distance from each warehouse to the customer. Add a flat rate weighting value to this total to compensate for each extra warehouse added to the supply chain.

Divide the result by the amount of stock to get a cost per unit figure of supplying from each warehouse. Order your database query on this column pick from the top until you have enough stock for the order.

So you have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stock` (
  `warehouse` char(11),
  `stock` int(10),
  `distance` int(10)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `stock` (`warehouse`, `stock`, 
`distance`)
VALUES
('A', 4, 3),
('B', 6, 8),
('C', 10, 10);
```

And you query it like this, where the 15 in `stock + 15` is the weighting value you want to add:

```
SELECT *, ((stock + 15) / distance) AS per_unit
FROM stock
ORDER BY stock DESC, per_unit ASC
```

Heres a [demo sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a63e4/9)

Comment: I like the idea of  flat rate weighting value. But I get confused at the divide part. Can you explain in a more visual way?

Comment: I've updated my answer and added a link to a demo. You divide by the number of units in stock to get a cost for delivering each unit. Then because of the weighting factor a warehouse 10 miles away with 10 items in stock will come out cheaper than 2 warehouses 5 miles away with 5 each. Likewise a warehouse 1 mile away with only 1 unit will have a high cost to deliver, which is what you want because it's not a cost effective option

Comment: I will definitely take this into account! What is 15 a product of? Or is it just randomly chosen?

Comment: It was just randomly chosen. You could add another column to your database table if you wanted to give different warehouses different weighting values depending on traffic in the local area or some other factor.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

It will first check to see if there is enough quantity. Else echo not enough.
But you have to deal with that somehow.
Then it will foreach loop with key being the warehouse and breakdown being the quantity in that house.
Subtract the amount possible or what is left of order and store the order in variable order.

```
$orderqt = 25;
if($orderqt <= $product_breakdown['storage']['10001']['total_stock']){
    foreach($product_breakdown['storage']['10001']['breakdown'] as $key => &$breakdown){
        if($orderqt>0){
            $possibleWarehouses = array_filter(
                $product_breakdown['storage']['10001']['breakdown'],
                function ($value) use($orderqt) {
                    return ($value >= $orderqt);
                }
            );

            if(count($possibleWarehouses) != 0){
                $house = key($possibleWarehouses);
                $order[$house] = $orderqt;
                $product_breakdown['storage']['10001']['breakdown'][$house] -= $orderqt;
                $orderqt = 0;
            }elseif($orderqt >= $breakdown){
                $orderqt -= $breakdown;
                $order[$key] = $breakdown;
                $breakdown = 0;
            }else{
                $order[$key] = $orderqt;
                $orderqt = 0;
                $breakdown -= $orderqt;
            }
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
}else{
    echo "not enough";
}
var_dump($order,$product_breakdown);
```

Added array_filter to see if any warehouse has the more than the orderd quantity.
$possibleWarehouses is an array that will hold warehouses that can fullfill the rest of the quantity that is ordered. 
In this case it will be NULL, NULL and then warehouse 9 with 10 in quantity.
https://3v4l.org/ZeUrt

Comment: To answer your question, because that would mean 4 packages instead of 3. Closeness is a factor but also to do it with the least steps (warehouses) possible.

Comment: @Borsn Yeah! I saw your comment. I just had to get my son to bed. Soon done with the fix

Comment: @Borsn See update with array_filter to find the warehouses with enough supply to fullfill the order.

Comment: This is a good starting point I think. When I tried 25 it says not enough despite there being 29 in stock. I think something should be added when it wants to exit the loop to return in back in when the total quantity says there is enough stock. I like the idea of `$possibleWarehouses`.

Comment: @Borsn Sorry forgot to update the "total stock" of the array when I replaced the quantity in the warehouses. The code looks at total stock. I'm guessing in real array it's updated automatically. Else I can switch to array_sum(). With 29 in total stock; https://3v4l.org/diZ3h

Comment: Right...I totally missed that. Yes it's automatically updated. I have another question, I updated total stock to 29. When I requested `25` I got  `[4] => 5,[1] => 5,[2] => 1,[10] => 8`; how can the `1` be eliminated? And also when I request `16` it gives me `[4] => 5,[1] => 5,[10] => 8` in this case  `'10'=>8, '9'=>10` would be more appropriate even though it's not the closest because it uses less warehouses.

Comment: @Borsn I found that bug you mention. I forgot to update the stocks in the warehouses. So in that case it takes from the same warehouses 5 several times. To remove the "1" it all needs to be restructured. This question is so far off what it was to start from now that it should be closed in my opinion. You asked for "closest warehouse" then "fullfill order" and now "remove small quantities". Seriously when will this end?!

Comment: I think it's very much on topic. When the allocation can be accomplished with 2 warehouses instead of 3, that should be the preferred choice. Thanks for your help, I'll definitely use the idea of `possibleWarehouses`...but needs more tinkering.

Comment: @Borsn no, if you had asked all of those questions in your  question it would have been put on hold for too broad.